# Supporting most common video formats cross browser

Tags: php, jquery, html, cross-browser

I am building an application where users can upload videos and its important to give them the flexibility of uploading most common video formats like .mov, .mp4. But I realised that browsers mostly don't support .mov and I tried many jQuery plugins that could help like JPlayer, LeanBack player but they did not help solving the problem. 
Searched answers on stackoverflow but none of them is satisfactory. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution for it. Please share.

Comment: @Andrew please let me know why you thought the question should be closed, it was a genuine question i was stuck for long. What makes it too broad? so that I know how to structure my questions form another time.But to be frank, this takes away the freedom of asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to find a middle program in between the user to the site to convert the video into a common format for playback. Finding a jQuery program for all file formats is pointless because there is so many of them.

YouTube figured out this problem quickly and [converts all their files to FLV files for playback.](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/internet/youtube/formats.html)

The most common file format for video out there is MPEG4. It is now used extensively in HTML5 video players because it can be viewed across all browsers and devices.

You could either:

- Have all videos be uploaded as mp4 files

---

- Have all the videos converted in between upload to playback using a service such as the [CloudConvert API](https://cloudconvert.com/apiconsole)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi, The idea of using cloud convert api is good and used it to convert files. I used form to upload the video that i need converted and used jquery to get the response back. The API does return back the output url which looks like //hostprmv2o.cloudconvert.com/download/46LlDMnqGBtKHFo7zWjE. And if I want i can go on the url and downlod the converted file. But I will have to do that manually. But in my case I would like my application to directly get the video and save it on the server. Do u know how that is possible, in case u have worked on it.

Comment: I haven't worked on it but if you can't find a service to convert it for you then I would only accept specific types of files. I would use jQuery to make sure it is an MP4 file and then allow users to submit.